# Best way to deploy applications on AWS ECS using docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, continuous-integration, amazon-ecs, docker-registry

I have a docker-compose file which deploys 3 services:

- front end angular
- back end spring boot
- DB MySQL

locally, works fine.
So now I trying to deploy it on a ecs instance and I'm getting a hard time on finding a way to do this.

There is a way to do it?
In the future, I want to automate all the process!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes since recently (end of 2020) there is way to do it, although i don't have experience with it first hand,

i can comment/reccomend the following:

https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-compose-for-amazon-ecs-now-available/

https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/blob/main/docs/ecs-compose-examples.md

You have to be aware that there are many aws specific resources to be created - by the compose cli, before you get it up and running like on your machine.

What i have experiece with is the Cloudformation way:

https://appfleet.com/blog/automate-docker-container-deployment-to-aws-ecs-using-cloudformation/

Where again, concepts are a bit different than a docker-compose (local) stack.

I suggest hopping on docker's slack and asking there for a hello-world proof-of-concept project;
https://www.docker.com/docker-community

EDIT:
You can find the 'hello world' at:
https://www.docker.com/blog/deploying-wordpress-to-the-cloud/

In respect to automation the key takeaway is that you will build the image with an automated tool (CICD tool) / or manually first and push it to AWS registry. From there a AWS ECS Task will fetch it and deploy it in one of the ECS available nodes.